# How to make a single query

Tags: sql-server

I am using mssql. I have these below queries in a loop to get records of 12 months.

Is it possible to make the below queries as single query.

I need to get report for all the months based on the team and dept.

```
select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='1' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='1' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'

select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='2' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='2' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'

select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='3' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='3' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'

.
.
.

select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='12' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='12' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'
```

**Table structure**

```
[proj_duration_map]( 
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [uid] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [dept] [nchar](25) NOT NULL,    
    [team] [nchar](200) NOT NULL,    
    [pid] [int] NOT NULL,    
    [week_val] [smallint] NOT NULL,   
    [month_val] [smallint] NULL,    
    [hour_val] [float] NOT NULL,
    [cur_month] [smallint] NULL,
    [year_val] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [last_updated] [datetime] NOT NULL
   )
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the version of `Sql Server`?

Comment: SQL server version 9.0

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi, there is no such version. Are you sure it is `Micosoft Sql Server`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want an aggregation.  To get the most recent `month_val` use window functions:

```
select team, dept, month_val, sum(hour_val)
from (select dm.*,
             max(cur_month) over (partition by month_val, team, dept) as max_curmonth
      from proj_duration_map dm
     ) dm
where team = 'M&T' and dept = 'GEF-SW' and cur_month = max_curmonth
group by team, dept, month_val;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `max_curmonth`?

Comment: query should get latest max_curmonth data. For example month_val can have data on cur_month 1,2. From the query should get latest cur_month(2)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff When I run my old query for month_val='1' it returns output as 351 but yours return '360'. It takes all the cur_month instead of max record

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri . . . It is being used now.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a union as below:

```
select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='1' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='1' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'

UNION ALL

select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='2' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='2' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'

UNION ALL

select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='3' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='3' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'

UNION ALL

select sum(hour_val) from proj_duration_map where
cur_month=(select max(cur_month) from proj_duration_map where 
month_val='12' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW') and
month_val='12' and team='M&T' and dept='GEF-SW'
```

Comment: I accept your answer as its only gives my exact result

Answer (score 3):

Alec's answer is correct and you can use union all, but why don't you just don't filter by month and instead GROUP BY them???
I believe a single query to be more elegant answer than a bunch linked by a UNION ALL clause...

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT SUM(hour_val) AS hour_val, 
       max(cur_month) AS cur_month, 
       month_val,year_val, team, dept 
FROM proj_duration_map 
GROUP BY month_val, year_val, team, dept
```

Comment: When I run my old query for month_val='1' it returns output as 351 but yours return '360'. It takes all the cur_month instead of max record

Comment: I have year_val in the query as well. That would be the reason for you to get a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PIVOT function and try this,

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
(SELECT id, uid, dept, team , week_val, month_val, hour_val HourWorked
FROM proj_duration_map) AS P 
PIVOT (sum(HourWorked) FOR month_val IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) as PVT
ORDER by uid, week_val
```

Comment: Nice answer for all the months. But it did not sum up individual months value, displays all the values based on individual months

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you totals for individual months grouped by dept and team

```
SELECT dept, team, 
SUM(x.[1]) month_1,
SUM(x.[2]) month_2,
SUM(x.[3]) month_3,
SUM(x.[4]) month_4,
SUM(x.[5]) month_5,
SUM(x.[6]) month_6,
SUM(x.[7]) month_7,
SUM(x.[8]) month_8,
SUM(x.[9]) month_9,
SUM(x.[10]) month_10,
SUM(x.[11]) month_11,
SUM(x.[12]) month_12
FROM 
(SELECT   dept , team , [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
FROM 
(SELECT id, uid, dept, team , week_val, month_val, hour_val HourWorked
FROM proj_duration_map) AS P 
PIVOT (sum(HourWorked) FOR month_val IN 
([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) as PVT)x
GROUP BY x.dept, x.team
```